# javascript replace() not replacing text containing literal \r\n strings

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, expression

Using this bit of code trims out hidden characters like carriage returns and linefeeds with nothing using javascript just fine:

```
value = value.replace(/[\r\n]*/g, "");
```

but when the code actually contains \r\n text what do I do to trim it without affecting r's and n's in my content?  I've tried this code:

```
value = value.replace(/[\\r\\n]+/g, "");
```

on this bit of text:

```
{"client":{"werdfasreasfsd":"asdfRasdfas\r\nMCwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADGw......
```

I end up with this:

```
{"cliet":{"wedfaseasfsd":"asdfRasdfasMCwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADGw......
```

Side note: It leaves the upper case versions of R and N alone because I didn't include the /i flag at the end and thats ok in this case.

What do I do to **just remove \r\n text** found in the string?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If you want to match literal `\r` and literal `\n` then you should use the following:

```
value = value.replace(/(?:\\[rn])+/g, "");
```

You might think that matching literal `\r` and `\n` with `[\\r\\n]` is the right way to do it and it is a bit confusing but it won't work and here is why:

Remember that in character classes, each single character represents a single letter or symbol, it doesn't represent a sequence of characters, it is just a *set* of characters.

So the character class `[\\r\\n]` actually matches the literal characters `\`, `r` and `n` as separate letters and not as sequences.

**Edit:** If you want to replace all carriage returns `\r`, newlines `\n` and also literal `\r` and '\n` then you could use:

```
value = value.replace(/(?:\\[rn]|[\r\n]+)+/g, "");
```

About `(?:)` it means a non-capturing group, because by default when you put something into a usual group `()` then it gets captured into a numbered variable that you can use elsewhere inside the regular expression itself, or latter in the matches array.

`(?:)` prevents capturing the value and causes less overhead than `()`, for more info see [this article](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Comment: Should I also be updating my first bit of code to `value = value.replace(/(\r|\n)+/g, "");` as well?  And what is the difference between the () and [] brackets in this case?

Comment: I've seen the ?: used before but I don't understand what it really does, can you elaborate on it's function?

Comment: @Vince I have improved the regular expression a bit more, if you have further questions please feel free to ask.

Comment: For my own sake I've stuck with your original suggestions till I get a little bit better at this stuff.  I've updated my first line of code to `value = value.replace(/(?:\r|\n)+/g, "");` and my second to `value = value.replace(/(?:\\r|\\n)+/g, "");` for now, ty to you and jfriend00 for your suggestions.

Comment: The edit for "\r, newlines \n and also literal \r and '\n`" worked very nicely, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

To just remove them, this seems to work for me:

```
value = value.replace(/[\r\n]/g, "");
```

You don't need the `*` after the character set because the `g` flag solves that for you.

Note, this will remove all `\r` or `\n` chars whether they are in this exact sequence or not.

Working demo of this option: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/57GtJ/

---

If you want to remove these characters only when in this exact sequence (e.g. only when a `\r` is directly followed by a `\n`, you could use this:

```
value = value.replace(/\r\n/g, "");
```

Working demo of this option: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Ta3sn/

Answer (score 6):

If you have text with a lot of \r\n and want to save all of them try this one

```
value.replace(/(?:\\[rn]|[\r\n])/g,"<br>")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/57GtJ/63/