# How to replace \\r\\n

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a string with several "\r\n" and I'm not sure how to replace it due to the several '\'. With normal '\r\n' I would do that

```
'some string \r\n' here'.replace(/\r\n/g, 'wtv');
```

But for this one I'm not sure:

```
// failed attempt below :(
'some string \\r\\n here'.replace('/\\r\\n/g', 'wtv);
```

Comment: `.replace(/\\r\\n/g, 'wtv')` - remove the single quotes to turn the string literal  to the regex literal. There must be a closing single quote after `wtv`, too.

Comment: You might want to read up a little more on regular expressions. The backslash is a special character in regular expressions, just like in string literals.

Comment: See this [question] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20023625/javascript-replace-not-replacing-text-containing-literal-r-n-strings). It will help

Comment: François, your code was ok, just the regex literal does not need to be put inside quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code :

```js
console.log("some string \\r\\n here".replace(/(?:\\[rn])+/g, "wtv"));
```

above code will replace all '\r\n' with 'wtv' in your string

Comment: It won't replace anything here. See the snippet results.

Comment: just a min. checking

Comment: Yeah, copied from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20023625/javascript-replace-not-replacing-text-containing-literal-r-n-strings

Comment: Working for me. Whether its copied or not, I found it here...